# What is causing the move constructor to be deleted

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I have the following sample:

```
#include <vector>

class noncopyable {
protected:
    noncopyable() {}
    ~noncopyable() {}
    noncopyable(const noncopyable&) = delete;
    noncopyable& operator=(const noncopyable&) = delete;
    noncopyable(noncopyable&&) = default;
    noncopyable& operator=(noncopyable&&) = default;
};

class C1 : private noncopyable {
public:
  C1() { }
  ~C1() { }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<C1> v;
    v.emplace_back();
    return 0;
}
```

I thought it should work since `C1` should be movable since it's base class is and it has no data members. Instead, I got an an error (using clang++):

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'C1'
    { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
                                     ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.
.
.
note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::vector<C1, std::allocator<C1> >::emplace_back<>' requested here
        v.emplace_back();
          ^
note: copy constructor of 'C1' is implicitly deleted because base class 'noncopyable' has a deleted copy constructor
class C1 : private noncopyable {
           ^
note: 'noncopyable' has been explicitly marked deleted here
        noncopyable(const noncopyable&) = delete;
```

Doing a little research (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) revealed that if there is a user-defined destructor then no implicit move-constructor will be defined. This seemes to be the problem here, since `C1` has a destructor, the move-constructor does not get defined. Sure enough, if I either remove the destructor or add `C1(C1&&) = default;` to `C1` then it works.

So far so good.

The problem was that the error message didn't mention `~C1()` or the move-constructor. It said it was trying to call the copy constructor, which was deleted in the base class. So I tried changing the `delete`ed functions in `noncopyable` to be `default`ed instead, and (surprise!), that also solved the error.

So my question is, what does this last thing have to do with the error or it's correction? If there is a destructor, what is the difference if the base class has the copy-constructor or not?

Comment: Try adding `noexcept` specifier.

Comment: Note there's a difference between "does not have a move constructor" and "has a deleted move constructor".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `vector`, a simpler example would be just:

```
C1 a;
C1 b(std::move(a)); // error: C1's copy constructor is deleted
```

From [class.copy]:

> If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move constructor, a non-explicit one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if
>   (9.1) — `X` does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
>   (9.2) — `X` does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
>   (9.3) — `X` does not have a user-declared move assignment operator, and
>   **(9.4) — `X` does not have a user-declared destructor.**

`C1` has a user-declared destructor, therefore it does not have a move constructor. `C1` *does* however have an implicitly declared copy constructor

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, **a non-explicit one is declared implicitly**. If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy
>   constructor is defined as deleted; **otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (8.4)**. The latter case is deprecated if the class has a user-declared copy assignment operator or a user-declared destructor.

The full set of constructors on `C1`, explicit and implicit, looks like:

```
C1();
C1(C1 const& ) = default; // but also delete
~C1();
```

So trying to construct a `C1` from an rvalue of type `C1` will match that implicitly declared copy constructor as the best match (nothing else is viable), but that constructor is `deleted` because `noncopyable`'s copy constructor is `deleted`, so the entire expression is ill-formed.

That's why the error message mentions the constructor. That move-construction is ill-formed because the best match for that move-construction is the copy constructor is ill-formed. It can't mention the move constructor because *there is no* move constructor, and the destructor isn't relevant to the expression at hand. When you changed the base class to be copyable, now `C1` also becomes copyable - so no error. There's still no move constructor, it's just that now there's a viable candidate for move construction.

Comment: How can a constructor be both `default` and `delete`? Also, can you please explain the last sentence in your second quote? What does it mean the the case is "deprecated"? Doesn't this mean that if I have a user-defined destructor I wont get the implicit copy-constructor (same as for the move-constructor)?

Comment: @baruch It's defaulted. But the default is ill-formed, so it's deleted. Deprecated just means that at some indeterminate point in the future, the functionality will change. Don't worry about it. I just included it for completeness.